# Does Firefox PCKS#11 modules support headless mode?

Tags: security, browser

Is it possible to use the PCKS#11 module of Firefox in headless mode?

I.e., for this scenario:
- use system console
- start Firefox in headless mode
- point it to a secured url
- PCKS#11 issues a console prompt for token instead of UI

Comment: why use a browser at all ?

Comment: What would you do?

Comment: I'd look at openssl and something like libp11 https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11 also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119744/pkcs11-engine-for-openssl and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=openssl+pkcs%2311